# php increase time string variable

Tags: php, time

I'm a beginner in php and I generate a random string that represents time with the code below :

```
$dep = mt_rand(0,23).":".str_pad(mt_rand(0,59), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //ex. "20:07:00"
```

I have searched here about how I can add time to a time variable

```
ex. "20:07" + 1 hour => "21:07"
```

but I didn't find something about how to add time when your variable is a string . If there is a way let me know or I will have to change my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) would be straightforward.

```
$time = '20:07';
echo date('H:i', strtotime($time . " +1 hour"));
```

[live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/573980d5d57c7dda276171e3b8fd6f47eed96281)

Comment: I tried $randTime = mt_rand(0,23).":".str_pad(mt_rand(0,59), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $dep = date('H:i',strtotime($randTime));
                $arr =  date('H:i' , strtotime($dep . + "1 hour"));  and the new hour is just 1:00:00 . Sorry I don't know how to place code in comments . I insert and view time in a mysql server , column is time format

Comment: @vasilis123 you didn't copy the exact code, there's an error in your code, specifically here `strtotime($dep . + "1 hour"))`

Comment: you don't need to change your `$dep` variable, use what was in the question

Comment: Beware that using date functions kind of works for times of day but not for durations (it'll wrap at 24 hours, or earlier depending on whether you hit daylight saving time boundaries).